# Extract single repeating XML node through whole XML result

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, extract, oracle-xml-db

Given the following XML sample below, how can I extract all `<table_no>` values from top to bottom using Oracle XML extraction.

Based on below, I would expect to see the following individual rows from my select:

```
1
4
2
11

Table: tickets
Column holding XML: ticket_col
```

XML code:

```
<xml>
  <ticket_order>
    <table_no>1<table_no/>
    <waiter>Jack<waiter/>
    <total_people>12<total_people/>
  </ticket_order>
  <ticket_order>
    <table_no>4<table_no/>
    <waiter>Jackie<waiter/>
    <total_people>3<total_people/>
  </ticket_order>
  <ticket_order>
    <table_no>2<table_no/>
    <waiter>Sally<waiter/>
    <total_people>2<total_people/>
  </ticket_order>
  <ticket_order>
    <table_no>11<table_no/>
    <waiter>Mike<waiter/>
    <total_people>6<total_people/>
  </ticket_order>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`XMLTable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/XMLTABLE.html#GUID-C4A32C58-33E5-4CF1-A1FE-039550D3ECFA);  with (fixed) sample XML as a string in-line:

```
select x.*
from xmltable(
 '/xml/ticket_order'
  passing xmltype('<xml>
  <ticket_order>
    <table_no>1</table_no>
    <waiter>Jack</waiter>
    <total_people>12</total_people>
  </ticket_order>
  <ticket_order>
    <table_no>4</table_no>
    <waiter>Jackie</waiter>
    <total_people>3</total_people>
  </ticket_order>
  <ticket_order>
    <table_no>2</table_no>
    <waiter>Sally</waiter>
    <total_people>2</total_people>
  </ticket_order>
  <ticket_order>
    <table_no>11</table_no>
    <waiter>Mike</waiter>
    <total_people>6</total_people>
  </ticket_order>
</xml>')
  columns table_no number path 'table_no'
) x;

  TABLE_NO
----------
         1
         4
         2
        11
```

If the XML is a string (VARCHAR2 or CLOB) in a table you would pass it in via a cross join:

```
select x.*
from your_table t
cross join xmltable(
  '/xml/ticket_order'
  passing xmltype(t.xml_string)
  columns table_no number path 'table_no'
) x;
```

If it's already am XMLType in the table you woudl skip that conversion:

```
select x.*
from your_table t
cross join xmltable(
  '/xml/ticket_order'
  passing t.xml
  columns table_no number path 'table_no'
) x;
```

You can get multiple columns at once; and the generated relatinal column name doesn't have to be the same as the node name:

```
select x.*
from your_table t
cross join xmltable(
  '/xml/ticket_order'
  passing t.xml
  columns table_number number path 'table_no',
    server varchar2(10) path 'waiter',
    covers number path 'total_people'
) x;

TABLE_NUMBER SERVER         COVERS
------------ ---------- ----------
           1 Jack               12
           4 Jackie              3
           2 Sally               2
          11 Mike                6
```

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-4805CF1C-A00D-4B88-AF2E-00A9DB6F3392).

Comment: Just have another query please - I have seen examples of the following nature: select xmltype(t.ticket_col).extract('//table_no/text()').getStringVal() from tickets t - will this pull out all 4 records that I am after?

Comment: @tonyf - no, it will get all the values, but concatenate them into one result - the single string '14211'. As would a single XMLQuery() call. XMLTable is designed to extract XML data as (multi-row) relational data.

Comment: OK - will use XMLQuery() and let you know.